# C# SQL Insert with a very large number of parameters

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I have had a problem for a few days and nothing online seems to do it.

I have an SQL table that has 150 columns. I am reading data from an ODBC connection and I want to insert that data into the SQL table. Basically duplicate the ODBC table as SQL.

My problem is that if I put everything in a string and insert it I face a hell of a time with escape characters and exceptions that I can't figure out.

Is there a way to parametrize my insert values that doesn't involve me naming each and every on of them separatly.

This is what I have right now. Also, if anyone knows an easier way to move an ODBC table to an SQL form please let me know

```
private void fillTable(string tableName)
    {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, Program.myConnection);
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

        int columnCount = reader.FieldCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            SqlCommand sCommand = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + tableName + " ADD " + reader.GetName(i) + " varchar(MAX)", Program.myConnection2);
            sCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        string row="";
        while (!reader.IsClosed)
        {
            try
            {
                row = "";
                reader.Read();
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                            if (reader.GetString(i).Contains('\''))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("REPLACED QUOT");
                                String s = reader.GetString(i).Replace("\'", "A");
                                Console.WriteLine(s);
                                row += s;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row += "\'" + reader.GetString(i).Trim() + "\',";
                            }

                       // Console.WriteLine("FILLER: " + reader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(row);
                }
                //Console.WriteLine();
                row = row.Substring(0, row.Length - 1);
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + tableName  + " VALUES(\'1\'," + row + ")", Program.myConnection2);
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exp.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(row);
               // this.Close();
            }
        }
        Program.myConnection2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Well, ODPC parameters are not named anyway. And yes, you could use a schema access to get the fields and - ah - parameters to have parameters. I would suggest you just sit down and try it and then come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Try to use dynamic sql command
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method that creats parameter names automatically, adds it to command, and returns the name so that you can use it in the query:

```
private int _paramCounter = 1;

private string CreateParameter(SqlCommand command, object value) {
  string name = "@P" + _paramCounter.ToString();
  _paramCounter++;
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
  return name;
}
```

Usage:

```
row += CreateParameter(insertCommand, reader.GetString(i).Trim()) + ",";
```

Note that you need to create the command object before you loop through the columns. Also, although not needed, you might want to reset the `_paramCounter` for each row, otherwise the parameter names get longer in the end.